# I need to discover the proper order of drives to restart a server that are in a raid 5 configuration with 6 hard drives

Tags: raid

i have a Dell Power Edge 750 server  machine with 6 hard drives of same size and running on raid 5. unfortunately during a service process of our data center one of the junior team members pulled out all four hard drives without labeling the actual sequence.

now i have following questions in mind:

1. can the raid controller automatically determine the actual sequence and rebuild the array without any data loss.
2. if not, is there any way to determine the actual order of hard drives

i cannot afford to loose the data on my drives. Can anybody suggest some authentic way out of this situation.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps `backup-restoration` isn't a good tag since it sounds like you don't have any backups.

Comment: What RAID controller is used on that server?

Comment: Image all the drives before you do anything else. If the data is critical, you *must* make a backup before you do *anything* else. (Why don't you already have one?!)

Comment: Normally it is not an issue for a modern hardware RAID controller to insert the disks in a different order. If you are running a software RAID it might be that the bootloader is only installed on one of the disks, which could prevent booting but should be solvable by putting the disks in a different order in the BIOS boot priority.

Comment: Hardware RAID controller or soft raid? If soft raid, I know Linux md is capable to address correctly disks even if unplugged and plugged in different order... But care! As @DavidSchwartz said! Backup now all raw disks if no already existant backup!

Comment: This question is not complete, the user who asked them won't answer to comments nor upvote or accept an answer because they are unregistered.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question, no, the RAID controller can not always determine the correct order of the drives.  Some newer RAID controllers may be able to, but many cannot.  Therefore, if you insert the drives in the wrong order, the data on them *may* be destroyed.  So, if you are not sure of the correct order of the drives, DO NOT reinsert them.

However, there is still hope for your precious data.  It is possible to determine the order of the RAID drives, and even recover the existing data, using a program called [ReclaiME Free Raid Recovery](http://www.freeraidrecovery.com/).  Best of luck getting your data back!